# concerns of software architecture

Tags: architecture

I am doing a report on Software Architecture and one of the sections which i need to write about is the issues that arise when using Software Architecture. I have tried to look online, read books etc but i can’t find anything to do with what the problems that will rise when using Software Architecture.

Any help on where i might be able to find anything would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this might be better suited for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) , although the question itself is awfully vague...

Answer (score 2):

Have a read through [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670). It covers *lots* of relevant topics.

Comment: Wow do you actually understand what the question is about?  (I ask that literally; I'm not making fun of you :-)

Comment: @Pointy: perhaps not, but I'm all out of close votes for the day. Maybe we're interpreting what the OP means by _"using software architecture"_ differently.

Comment: Well the question makes me confused; the way I see it, if you write software at all, there's an "architecture" there, whether you put it there on purpose or not :-)  Thus I don't really understand the idea of a topic concerning "issues that arise when using Software Architecture" unless it's about a *particular* one.  But I've now spent way more time thinking about it than the thing deserves :-)

Comment: @Pointy: I agree, it's a pretty lousy question, and that we've now _both_ spent more time on it than it deserves :). I assumed that the question was asking about problems that arise in the process of software *engineering*.

Comment: Sorry, my question is awful! I am doing a Software Architecture module and i have to write a report on it. One of the sections which i have to cover within this report is "concerns arising from the use of software architecture". Sorry if this didnt help but im not sure how else i can describe my problem. Thanks

Comment: @yemyem: and yet, that does not clarify the question in any way. :(

Comment: The problem with your question yemyem is your use of the phrase, "software architecture".  You are treating it as if it is a specific noun.  It is not.  Your question is similar to asking what cancerns arise from using things."